# Cron Job - php script - multiple users?

Tags: php, curl, cron

What is the best way to perform cron-job automation for multiple users?

**Example**:

A cron-job needs to run every 10 minutes an call a PHP script that connects to an  external API (**via curl**) and collects data (site visitors and other data) a user has received on an external web property. We need to check periodically every 10 minutes via the API if there is any new data available for that user and fetch it -- and that **for EACH user** in the web-app.

Such cron-job PHP script call to the API usually takes 1-3 seconds per user, but could occasionally take up to 30 seconds or more to complete for one user (in exceptional situations).

**Question**...

What is the best way to perform this procedure and collect external data like that for MULTIPLE users? **Hundreds, even thousands of users?**

For each user, we need to check for data every 10 minutes.

Originally I was thinking of calling 10 users in a row in a loop with one cron-job call, but since each user collection can take 30 seconds...for 10 users a loop could take several minutes and...the script could timeout? Correct?

Do you have some tips and suggestions on how to perform this procedure for many users most efficiently? Should separate cron jobs be used for each user? Instead of a loop?

Thank you!

=== EDIT ===

Let's say one PHP script can call the API for 10 users within 1 minute... Could I create 10 cron-jobs that essentially call the same PHP script simultaneously, but each one collecting a different batch of 10 users? This way I could potentially get data for 100 users within one minute? No?

It could look like this:

/usr/local/bin/php -q get_data.php?users_group=1

/usr/local/bin/php -q get_data.php?users_group=2

/usr/local/bin/php -q get_data.php?users_group=3

and so on...

Is this going to work?

=== NOTE ===

Each user has a unique Access Key with the external API service, so one API call can only be for one user at a time. But the API could receive multiple simultaneous calls for different users at once.

Comment: scripts called by cli (including cron) have no time limit. that said,  30 seconds every 10 minutes for thousands of users is obviously not going to work

Comment: Let's say I have 10 separate cron jobs calling the same php script almost simultaneously...is this going to work? Thing is, most times each API call for each user takes 1-3 seconds. Only VERY rarely it could take 10 seconds (the most I've experienced), and I put 30 seconds just to make sure... if the server of the API provider is jammed or so...

Comment: cheap multi threading - i do this but limit the # of processes to the number of cores. after that all they do is cue up and you get no benefit

Answer (score 2):

If it takes 30 seconds a user and you have more than 20 users, you won't finish before you need to start again.  I would consider using [GearMan](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) or other job server to handle each of these requests in an async way.  GearMan can also wait for jobs to complete, so you should be able to loop over all the requests you need to make and then wait for them to finish.  You can probably accomplish the same thing with PHP's pthread implementation, however, that's going to be significantly more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. Interesting. Yes, the API call only very rarely will take more than 2-3 seconds. Peak I've experienced is about 10 seconds, because there's also another loop on their side going and...their server could be jammed at times. I wanted to just make sure...that's why "up to 30 seconds". I already have a PHP script that queues all users and all their tasks in a row so they execute few at a time. Thanks again for the tips. I'll look into it.